# Magento 2 : Error "TypeError: Return value of Magento\Framework\Filter\DirectiveProcessor\TemplateDirective::process() must be of the type string"

Tags: magento2, email

I am facing "**TypeError: Return value of Magento\Framework\Filter\DirectiveProcessor\TemplateDirective::process() must be of the type string**" error while sending sales email like (order confirmation,credit memo. shipment) etc

Here are some details

```
Magento/2.4 (Enterprise)

PHP 7.3.27-9+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2021 15:10:08) ( NTS )
```

Please share your thoughts on this how to fix it ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I'm having this exact issue

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I received the email I got this error message "**Error filtering template: Argument 'value' must be type of string, NULL given.**"

Apparently this came because I had the "subject" field poorly defined in the email template.

I have updated it this way in the template and it works, in case it helps you:

```
<!-- This is the subject of the email -->
<!--@subject {{trans "This is your custom subject"}} @-->
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks. it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your email templates. Maybe a variable you add returns a type other than string

Comment: I'm having this issue, I've removed all content from email templates and just left a simple string....but this issue is still showing??